# Continue PHP execution after sending HTTP response

Tags: php, fork

How can I have PHP 5.2 (running as apache mod_php) send a complete HTTP response to the client, and then keep executing operations for one more minute?

**The long story:**

I have a PHP script that has to execute a few long database requests and send e-mail, which takes 45 to 60 seconds to run. This script is called by an application that I have no control over. I need the application to report any error messages received from the PHP script (mostly invalid parameter errors).

The application has a timeout delay shorter than 45 seconds (I do not know the exact value) and therefore registers every execution of the PHP script as an error. Therefore, I need PHP to send the complete HTTP response to the client as fast as possible (ideally, as soon as the input parameters have been validated), and then run the database and e-mail processing.

I'm running mod_php, so `pcntl_fork` is not available. I could work my way around this by saving the data to be processed to the database and run the actual process from `cron`, but I'm looking for a shorter solution.

Comment: Sorry, but this looks like a total misuse of the PHP language.

Comment: Not as much as misuse of the PHP language as misuse of a webserver process. If no HTTP / web is involved anymore no webserver should be busy with it.

Comment: System abuse or not, sometimes we must do things we don't like due to requirements outside of our control. Doesn't make the question invalid, just makes the situation unfortunate.

Comment: I don't see how this is abuse, at all. If it is, someone should tell Amazon to shut down amazon.com, since most of the work involved in packing and shipping an order takes place after the purchase web request is completed. Either that, or set a two week timeout on amazon.com purchase requests and only deliver the response to the browser once the order has been delivered to the customer.

Comment: Does this solution work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265073/php-background-processes/265090#265090 ?

Comment: let's try to keep personal opinions to ourselves. answer the question or go elsewhere, please.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have the script that handles the initial request create an entry in a processing queue, and then immediately return. Then, create a separate process (via cron maybe) that regularly runs whatever jobs are pending in the queue.

Comment: This the solution I originally had in mind. On the other hand, setting up a processing queue for the sole purpose of working around a timeout in a third party application makes me feel a bit uneasy.

Comment: This solution suffers from lack of parallelism... or one will need to start a pool of worker-proccesses to serve the queue. I ended up posting and then disconnecting http requests to self-localhost (in a manner described by SomeGuy here) to utilize a pool of existing httpd workers as background processors.

Answer (score 52):

I had this snippet in my "special scripts" toolbox, but it got lost (clouds were not common back then), so I was searching for it and came up with this question, surprised to see that it's missing, I searched more and came back here to post it:

```
<?php
 ob_end_clean();
 header("Connection: close");
 ignore_user_abort(); // optional
 ob_start();
 echo ('Text the user will see');
 $size = ob_get_length();
 header("Content-Length: $size");
 ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
 flush();            // Unless both are called !
 session_write_close(); // Added a line suggested in the comment
 // Do processing here 
 sleep(30);
 echo('Text user will never see');
?>
```

I actually use it in few places. And it totally makes sense there: a banklink is returning the request of a successful payment and I have to call a lot of services and process a lot of data when that happens. That sometimes takes more than 10 seconds, yet the banklink has fixed timeout period. So I acknowledge the banklink and show him the way out, and do my stuff when he is already gone.

Comment: I advice to add ```session_write_close();``` after ```flush();``` if you are using sessions, otherwise you will not be able to use your site (in the same browser tab) until your (background) processing finish.

Comment: Interesting approach, but unfortunately it doesn't work if you're running behind varnish or, presumably, other proxies.

Comment: it doesnt work on php5 and chrome browser on linux, chrome waits 30 seconds before terminating the connection

Comment: The `ignore_user_abort(); // optional` would have no effect, without passing a value (Boolean) that function returns the current setting.

Comment: I tested this solution on my shared hosting, and "Text user will never see" was shown after 30 seconds waiting.

Comment: There should be `ignore_user_abort(true);` instead of `ignore_user_abort();`

Comment: `if (ob_get_length() > 0 ) {
ob_end_clean();
}`
fixes this error: 
`ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete`

Comment: I've suggested edit to this reponse with your comments @JarekJakubowski / Aldo

Answer (score 8):

What you need is this kind of setup

[image]

Comment: Umm, but, based on this diagram, status message gets sent back to client only when cron executes - 5-10 minutes maximum. Anyway, nice diagram!

Comment: status messages could be requested at any time :) the point was that there are two separate and independent processes going on here. But otherwise, thanks!

Comment: +1 Wow, great diagram! But instead of the user requesting the status continuously, I think that websockets are better.

Answer (score 8):

One can to use "http fork" to oneself or any other script. I mean something like this:

```
// parent sript, called by user request from browser

// create socket for calling child script
$socketToChild = fsockopen("localhost", 80);

// HTTP-packet building; header first
$msgToChild = "POST /sript.php?&param=value&<more params> HTTP/1.0\n";
$msgToChild .= "Host: localhost\n";
$postData = "Any data for child as POST-query";
$msgToChild .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($postData)."\n\n";

// header done, glue with data
$msgToChild .= $postData;

// send packet no oneself www-server - new process will be created to handle our query
fwrite($socketToChild, $msgToChild);

// wait and read answer from child
$data = fread($socketToChild, $dataSize);

// close connection to child
fclose($socketToChild);
...
```

Now the child script:

```
// parse HTTP-query somewhere and somehow before this point

// "disable partial output" or 
// "enable buffering" to give out all at once later
ob_start();

// "say hello" to client (parent script in this case) disconnection
// before child ends - we need not care about it
ignore_user_abort(1);

// we will work forever
set_time_limit(0);

// we need to say something to parent to stop its waiting
// it could be something useful like client ID or just "OK"
...
echo $reply;

// push buffer to parent
ob_flush();

// parent gets our answer and disconnects
// but we can work "in background" :)
...
```

The main idea is:

- parent script called by user request;
- parent calls child script (same as parent or another) on the same server (or any other server) and gives request data to them;
- parent says ok to user and ends;
- child works.

If you need to interact with child - you can use DB as "communication medium": parent may read child status and write commands, child may read commands and write status. If you need that for several child scripts - you should keep child id on the user side to discriminate them and send that id to parent each time you want to check status of respective child.

I've found that here - http://linuxportal.ru/forums/index.php/t/22951/

Comment: This approach (slightly modified) is the only working solution I found to create background task from apache's mod_php _without_ overhead of starting separate OS process - this will occupy and use one of already existing httpd workers instead

Comment: In the parent script's `fread($socketToChild, $dataSize)`, where does `$dataSize` come from? Do you need to know exactly how much data to expect out of the socket (including size of headers)? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 5):

What about calling a script on the file server to execute as if it had been triggered at the command line?  You can do this with PHP's [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: +1, something like `Gearman` is already set up for it (but other / ones own solutions are of course equally valid).

Comment: exec() is often a problem in shared/hosted spaces. Plus a huge security risk.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the PHP function [register-shutdown-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) that will execute something *after* the script has completed its dialog with the browser.

See also [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) - but you shouldn't need this function if you use the register_shutdown_function. On the same page, `set_time_limit(0)` will prevent your script to time out.

Comment: Apparently, according to the docs, register_shutdown_function is called before the script completed the dialog since 4.1.0. Your other link, however, contains a promising comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#89177 I'll try to delve deeper into this and report back here.

Answer (score 4):

Using a queue, exec or cron would be an overkill to this simple task.
There is no reason not to stay within the same script.
This combination worked great for me:

```
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        $response = "some response"; 
        header("Connection: close");
        header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($response));
        echo $response;
        flush(); // releasing the browser from waiting
        // continue the script with the slow processing here...
```

read more in:
[How to continue process after responding to ajax request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481247/how-to-continue-process-after-responding-to-ajax-request-in-php)

Comment: You may need to disable additional buffering which occurs in Apache: ```<?php
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);?>```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use cURL for that, with a very short timeout. This would be your main file:

```
<?php>
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/processor.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 10);      //just some very short timeout
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And this your processor file:

```
<?php
    ignore_user_abort(true);                       //very important!
    for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++)                     //do some very time-consuming task
        sleep(10);
?>
```

As you can see, the upper script will timeout after a short time (10 milliseconds in this case). It is possible that `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` will not work like this, in this case, it would be equivalent to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1)`.

So when the processor file has been accessed, it will do its tasks no matter that the user (i.e. the calling file) aborts the connection.

Of course you can also pass GET or POST parameters between the pages.

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this problem for quite a while now and this one works! Thanks a lot.

The other solutions might work in specific scenarios, except if you have have limited control over your webserver only and can't fork new processes; a configuration I commonly find on commercial webservers. This solution still works!

One important addition. For UNIX systems you need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);` for timeouts < 1 sec to work. 
Check here for the [explanation](https://ravidhavlesha.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/curl-timeout-problem-and-solution/).

Comment: finally, genuine!

Comment: My processor script didn't execute, so I increased `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` to `100`. It works like a charm, and enables me to quickly respond when receiving events from our payment provider.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an http request between server and server. (not browser is needed).
The secret to create a background http request is setting a very small timeout, so the response is ignored.

This is a working function that I have used for that pupose:

MAY
31
PHP asynchronous background request
Another way to create an asynchronous request in PHP (simulating background mode).

```
 /**
  * Another way to make asyncronous (o como se escriba asincrono!) request with php
  * Con esto se puede simpular un fork en PHP.. nada que envidarle a javita ni C++
  * Esta vez usando fsockopen
  * @author PHPepe
  * @param  unknown_type $url
  * @param  unknown_type $params
  */
 function phpepe_async($url, $params = array()) {
  $post_params = array(); 
     foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
       if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
         $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
     }
     $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

     $parts=parse_url($url);

     $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
         isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
         $errno, $errstr, 30);

     $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
     $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
     $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
     $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
     $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
     if (isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

     fwrite($fp, $out);
     fclose($fp);
 }

 // Usage:
 phpepe_async("http://192.168.1.110/pepe/feng_scripts/phprequest/fork2.php");
```

For more info you can take a look at 
http://www.phpepe.com/2011/05/php-asynchronous-background-request.html

Answer (score 0):

Bah, I misunderstood your requirements. Looks like they're actually:

- Script receives input from an external source you do not control
- Script processes and validates the input, and lets the external app know if they're good or not and terminates the session.
- Script kicks off a long-running proccess.

In this case, then yes, using an outside job queue and/or cron would work. After the input is validated, insert the job details into the queue, and exit. Another script can then run, pick up the job details from the queue, and kick off the longer process. Alex Howansky has the right idea.

Sorry, I admit I skimmed a bit the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

You can split these functions into three scripts.
1. Initiate process and call second one via exec or `command`, this is also possible to run via http call.
2. second one will run database processing and at the end will start last one
3. last one will email

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend spawning a new async request at the end, rather than continuing the process with the user.

You can spawn the other request using the answer here:
[Asynchronous PHP calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/asynchronous-php-calls/2924987#2924987)

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache `php.ini` config file, make sure that output buffering is disabled:

```
output_buffering = off
```