# Make an async ajax request when clicking on a link

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm using PHP/jQuery and have the following scenario:

I have a site (`site1.php`) with a link, which points to another site (`site2.php`), also I added to this link an ajax-onclick-event with jQuery which requests another site (`ajaxcall.php`). This other site has "a lot of work" to do, so it's not a short request.

My goal is: Set the request to `ajaxcall.php` in the background (asynchron) AND go immediately to `site2.php`. (I do not need an answer of `ajaxcall.php`)

My first implementation was like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#link").on("click",function(){
            $.get('./ajaxcall.php');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="./file2.php" id="link">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously this won't work. Because the ajax-request (which is async), is aborted as soon as the page is changed.

So as far as I can see I have two possiblities here:

1. Make the request synchron & show a loading indicator (`$.ajax({url: './ajaxcall.php',async:false});`)
   --> Disadvantage: `file2.php` will not open before the `ajaxcall.php` is done.
2. Open a popup (`window.open('ajaxcall.php')`) and make a synchron-ajax-request / or something similar there and auto-close it after that
   --> Advantage: `file2.php` should open almost immediately
   --> (Big)Disadvantage: Popup
3. ??? A better way ???

I hope you understood what I'm trying to accomplish and that you can help me :)

Comment: It's not clear to me WHY you want to open two files at once. How you solve this problem depends in part on what you want to happen.

Comment: PHP has [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php). Your `ajaxcall.php` script should run unaffected by a client loading a different page.

Comment: well the  `ajaxcall.php` will generate a report via a reportserver (tomcat) which is than saved on the linux machine below  - and I don't want to wait until this is done

Comment: @Tomalak will try your answer (tomorrow :P) "together" with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response and post if it worked...

Comment: The first call is not "aborted".  The client can't abort a request that's already been made.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $.get('./ajaxcall.php', function() {
            window.location.href = href;
        });
    });
});
```

It stops execution of the link (with `e.preventDefault()`), gets the target url and then redirects the page to that location when the get request is complete.

Comment: I know this. This doesn't solve my problem. It's just another way of doing it synchron.

Comment: That's not synchronous - it's asynchronous.  I don't think I understand your question though, as that's how I read it.

Answer (score 0):

Well couldn't you just start the action within `ajaxcall.php` by passing a parameter to `file2.php`?
So like:

`file2.php?startBackgroundAction=true`

**file2.php:**

```
if($_GET['startBackgroundAction']) {
   include 'ajaxCall.php' // with ignore_user_abort(true)
}
```

Comment: Your answer lacks specifics.

Comment: not really because it may be that `file2.php` won't stay "open" for long, because there are also other links to other pages on it...

Answer (score 0):

Latest chrome browser wont complete the ajax request. Since the browser page got new url request from the user, so browser will kill the thread immediately.

98% of times you can see that the ajax request got cancelled in a network tab.

So the solution is use sendBeacon API. This will perform a POST request asynchronously.
Google analytics uses this code to perform the event trackings (Ex: click).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

```
 navigator.sendBeacon("{{url}}", param);
```