# continue php script execution called by ajax after

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a page called call.php with this codes

```
    <script src="http://localhost/js/jquery.js"></script>   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.post("exe.php",
            { 
                a: 'a'
            },
            function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    </script>   
///close tabs after onload
```

and in exe.php i have this code

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(60);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    sleep(20);

    $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
?>
```

i need to continue php execution even after closing tab immediately
it works fine in localhost using WAMP
but in my host doesn't work it stops after perhaps 10-14 secs
in localhost and server ignore_user_abort(true) is off
the question is : turning this function ON solves the problem? and why in localhost  it works even when this function is off

### my execution takes about 30 sec times i need to get it working

**EDIT**

i tried something like this

```
<?php
    ignore_user_abort(true);
function shutdown()
{
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/2.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/4.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/6.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/8.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/10.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/12.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/14.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/16.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/18.txt',"w");
    sleep(2);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/20.txt',"w");
}
//register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
shutdown();
?>
```

opened tab and closed immediately after if completely loaded
this code created 2.txt ... 10.txt
so certainly there is an option which shuts down script after 10 secs

Comment: I thinks this is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, PHP will buffer the output to a certain amount of Bytes (last time I tested, I believe it was 2048). As long as PHP does not try to flush that buffer, it will not detect a closed connection, and so it will not abort the script. On Linux that buffer works differently and most importantly does not ignore `flush()`.

As to why your `ignore_user_abort(true)` call *"does not work"* (this kind of sentence is not a good error report and will not likely result in your getting a good answer) I can not possibly know.

- You could however try to use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) instead.
- You could also try increasing the max execution time using a `.htaccess` file. The syntax is quite easy

  ```
  php_flag max_execution_time 120
  ```
- The web server itself also may have an execution time limit that may abort your script, see [TimeOut](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) for example.

Comment: what did you try, how did it not work. And yes. Since `set_time_limit()` and `max_execution_time` are both disabled when in safe mode. Also note that [**safe mode**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and removed (throws a fatal error) in PHP 5.4 and above

Comment: Tried this code
<?php
 ignore_user_abort(true);
function shutdown()
{
 sleep(20);
 $file = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/logs/aaaa.txt',"w");
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

?>
opened call.php after 2-3 second closed tab ,after 20 secs file did not created,also i closed tab after 14 secs but still file didnt created,although it works by not closing tab

Comment: I think this has to be a configuration issue, for starters get a host without `safe_mode`, it's not safer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function.

Definition:

> Set whether a client disconnect should abort script execution

**Warning:** Be careful with this, the only way to kill an infinite loop would be to kill the web server/PHP depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ignore_user_abort` and `set_time_limit` before you call `sleep`.