# Running Processes Asynchronously in symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I would like to run a process on my controller and while the process is running my twig page should be shown.

Here is my code:

```
$cmd="my command ";
$process = new Process('');
$process->setCommandLine($cmd);

return $this->render('sendForm.html.twig');

$process->start();
```

Comment: Well for starters you have the return statement before you actually start your process.

Comment: so i did put the return after but don't work too

Comment: Did you also read [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)?

Comment: i did use it but the but the server kill me process before end

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. Use something else to decouple the processes. Just store the job you wan to run, and cron job or something like that to consume the pending tasks. Symfony has Messenger which is perfectly suited for this, but the logic is the same: store the "task" in some sort of queue, and have a different processes execute the pending tasks.

Comment: You can use EventSubscriber or EventListener for that. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219537/symfony-run-code-after-response-was-sent