# Making PHP's mail() asynchronous

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-ses

I have PHP's `mail()` using [ssmtp](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ssmtp) which doesn't have a queue/spool, and is synchronous with AWS SES.

I heard I could use [SwiftMail](http://swiftmailer.org/) to provide a spool, but I couldn't work out a simple recipe to use it like I do currently with `mail()`.

I want the least amount of code to provide asynchronous mail. I don't care if the email fails to send, but it would be nice to have a log.

Any simple tips or tricks? Short of running a full blown mail server? I was thinking a `sendmail` wrapper might be the answer but I couldn't work out `nohup`.

Comment: exec('php mailcript.php ...

Comment: idea: store the mail somewhere as queue instead of sending, and use a background script to send from the queue.

Comment: use Threads, they are async: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php#114752

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of using threads to quickly send mail() off in the background please?

Comment: Does the normal sending with PHPs mail() function works fine for you?

Comment: `I want the least amount of code to provide` - SO is not a place to beg for code. This "question" should already be closed. Using "bounty" to prevent as you did simply sucks.

Comment: If you want to queue mails and send them asynchronously, just switch to a smtpd that has one. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: mail() works but it's synchronous @JRsz. I don't want to run a full smtpd. I'm using ssmtp.

Comment: Since you are using Amazon SES, why dont you just use the API? It allows for async sending. Cf. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-email-2010-12-01.html#sendemail

Comment: @hendry I have used `nohup` and generated separate script for async functionality. Do you want to use `nohup` then I can put code as an answer.

Comment: Parixit, please contribute the nohup wrapper / sample. I'm interested.

Comment: Idea : Its does not matter which php mailer you are using. You  just have to set "TO" (Mail id to whom you want to send email) with comma and send mail. Try it.

Comment: Lol, I tried it. It took 5.1seconds.

Comment: POST the email message to SNS instead. Have SNS trigger the actual email sending code upon new message.

Comment: I don't want to depend on AWS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### php-fpm

You must run php-fpm for [fastcgi_finish_request](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) to be available.

```
echo "I get output instantly";
fastcgi_finish_request(); // Close and flush the connection.
sleep(10); // For illustrative purposes. Delete me.
mail("test@example.org", "lol", "Hi");
```

It's pretty easy queuing up any arbitrary code to processed after finishing the request to the user:

```
$post_processing = [];
/* your code */
$email = "test@example.org";
$subject = "lol";
$message = "Hi";

$post_processing[] = function() use ($email, $subject, $message) {
  mail($email, $subject, $message);
};

echo "Stuff is going to happen.";

/* end */

fastcgi_finish_request();

foreach($post_processing as $function) {
  $function();
}
```

#### Hipster background worker

Instantly time-out a curl and let the new request deal with it. I was doing this on shared hosts before it was cool. *(it's never cool)*

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
  sleep(10);
  mail($_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
  exit(); // Stop so we don't self DDOS.
}

$ch = curl_init("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
  'email' => 'noreply@example.org',
  'subject' => 'foo',
  'message' => 'bar'
]);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "Expect an email in 10 seconds.";
```

Comment: I am using php-fpm, but that approach makes me have to structure my mail() carefully to be on the south side of `fastcgi_finish_request();`  I don't quite follow the curl example. You timeout the curl request even though it probably got the request out ... ?!?

Comment: @hendry 1. Just make an execution queue for later. I've added an example.  2. requestA send a POST to itself starting requestB. The timeout causes the curl to return almost immediately so that the user initiated request can continue executing. Now concurrently requestA continues to the `echo` statement and exits and concurrently requestB continues to send the email.

Answer (score 18):

You have a lot of ways to do this, but handling thread is not necessarily the right choice.

- **[register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function)**: the shutdown function is called after the response is sent. It's not really asynchronous, but at least it won't slow down your request. Regarding the implementation, see the example.
- **[Swift pool](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html)**: using symfony, you can easily use the spool.
- **Queue**: register the mails to be sent in a queue system (could be done with RabbitMQ, MySQL, redis or anything), then run a cron that consume the queue. Could be done with something as simple as a MySQL table with fields like `from`, `to`, `message`, `sent` (boolean set to `true` when you have sent the email).

### Example with register_shutdown_function

```
<?php
class MailSpool
{
  public static $mails = [];

  public static function addMail($subject, $to, $message)
  {
    self::$mails[] = [ 'subject' => $subject, 'to' => $to, 'message' => $message ];
  }

  public static function send() 
  {
    foreach(self::$mails as $mail) {
      mail($mail['to'], $mail['subject'], $mail['message']);
    }
  }
}

//In your script you can call anywhere
MailSpool::addMail('Hello', 'contact@example.com', 'Hello from the spool');


register_shutdown_function('MailSpool::send');

exit(); // You need to call this to send the response immediately
```

Comment: And that code executes quickly? Isn't it synchronous on shutdown?

Comment: The register_shutdown_function is synchronous, but it is executed AFTER the response is sent to the client, so it does not matter if the sending takes 10s for instance.

Comment: Takes almost 5 seconds in my test for the response to complete. :(

Comment: Your test might be wrong. Maybe you can pastebin your whole test

Comment: `exit` doesn't exit the process and close the connection when a shutdown function is registered. If you replaced the last 2 lines of code with `MailSpool::send();` the exact same thing would be happening.

Comment: Had to sent an email after status change, did with register_shutdown_function and it suited my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up using this method for sending emails asynchronously. However, I am having one big problem. Some emails are being CC'd to mails that don't have to be there and that causes confusion and frustration. Why's that?

Comment: `register_shutdown_function` was't executing after the response was sent for me (php 7), so I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15273676/7427553)

Answer (score 4):

Use AWS SES with **PHPMailer**.

This way is very fast (hundreds of messages per second), and there isn't much code required.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'ssl://email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication

$mail->Username = 'blah';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'blahblah';                           // SMTP password


$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 443;
```

Not sure if i interpreted your question correctly but i hope this helps.

Comment: Still makes the Web response takes four seconds. :/

Comment: It might not help for this case but also a great solution I think. Thanks.

Comment: It won't send emails asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

[Pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) is your friend :)
This is a sample of how i made in my production application

```
class AsynchMail extends Thread{
    private $_mail_from;
    private $_mail_to;
    private $_subject;

    public function __construct($subject, $mail_to, ...) {
        $this->_subject = $subject;
        $this->_mail_to = $mail_to;
        // ... 
    }
    // ...
    // you must redefine run() method, and to execute it we must call start() method
    public function run() {
        // here put your mail() function
        mail($this->_mail_to, ...);
    }
}
```

**TEST SCRIPT EXAMPLE**

```
$mail_to_list = array('Shigeru.Miyamoto@nintendo.com', 'Eikichi.Kawasaki@neogeo.com',...);
foreach($mail_to_list as $mail_to) {
    $asynchMail = new AsynchMail($mail_to);
    $asynchMail->start();
}
```

Let me know if you need further help for installing and using thread in PHP
For logging system, i strongly advice you to use [Log4PHP](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/) : powerful and easy to use and to configure
For sending mails, i also strongly advice you to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Be good to get a self contained sample in a file so I can run and test it please!

Comment: Why would you use threads if you already have `php-fpm` available? You just chose to occupy a cpu core by spawning a thread from a process, instead of letting that process do its synchronous work. Threads do absolutely nothing useful here in terms of.. anything except wasting resources.

Comment: @N.B. According to the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php): `Warning
The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server environment. Threading in PHP should therefore remain to CLI-based applications only.`

Comment: @Michael so why are you higlighting me exactly? I don't really follow. The extension was made so it can be used with mod_php, or php-fpm, it still can if you know what to change at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using asynchronous php execution by using [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/).
It is a simple message queue, really lightweight and easy to integrate.

Using the following php wrapper for php https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk
you can do something as follows to implement a email worker:

```
use Beanstalk\Client;
$msg="dest_email##email_subject##from_email##email_body";

$beanstalk = new Client(); 
$beanstalk->connect();
$beanstalk->useTube('flux'); // Begin to use tube `'flux'`.
$beanstalk->put(
    23,  // Give the job a priority of 23.
    0,   // Do not wait to put job into the ready queue.
    60,  // Give the job 1 minute to run.
    $msg // job body
);
$beanstalk->disconnect();
```

Then the job would be done in a code placed into a separate php file.
Something like:

```
use Beanstalk\Client;
$do=true;

try {
    $beanstalk = new Client();
    $beanstalk->connect();
    $beanstalk->watch('flux');

} catch (Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    $do = false;
}

while ($do) {
    $job = $beanstalk->reserve(); // Block until job is available.
    $emailParts = explode("##", $job['body'] );

    // Use your SendMail function here

    if ($i_am_ok) {
        $beanstalk->delete($job['id']);
    } else {
        $beanstalk->bury($job['id'], 20);
    }
}
$beanstalk->disconnect();
```

You can run separately this php file, as an independent php process. Let's say you save it as *sender.php*, it would be run in Unix as:

`php /path/to/sender/sender.php & && disown`

This command would run the file and alsow allow you to close the console or logout current user without stopping the process.
Make sure also that your web server uses the same php.ini file as your php command line interpreter. (*Might be solved using a link to you favorite php.ini*)

I hope it helps.

Comment: 8k LOC of C for beanstalkd and a package for something I expect to take one line of code? No.

Comment: I just depends if you want a quick *whatever* o a *integral solution*. I answer for the second one, just in case.

Comment: You're better of using `nohup` rather than `disown` http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/3125

Comment: good to read, very useful. For this example it works with `& && disown` because the executed process does not get input from the console session.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to call the code which handles your mails asynchronously.

For example if you have a file called **email.php** with the following code:

```
// Example array with e-mailaddresses
$emailaddresses = ['example1@test.com', 'example2@example.com', 'example1@example.com'];

// Call your mail function
mailer::sendMail($emailaddresses);
```

You can then call this asynchronously in a normal request like

```
exec('nice -n 20 php email.php > /dev/null & echo $!');
```

And the request will finish without waiting for **email.php** to finish sending the e-mails. Logging could be added as well in the file that does the e-mails.

Variables can be passed into the exec between the called filename and `> /dev/null` like

```
exec('nice -n 20 php email.php '.$var1.' '.$var2.' > /dev/null & echo $!');
```

Make sure these variables are safe with [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php). In the called file these variables can be used with [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Comment: How do you feed the variables of the mail() command into the exec?

Comment: I have updated the post with an example of this. It may be easier to have all your needed variables in a seperate config file and just include that into the called file.

Comment: This is 1 user input away from being an RCE vulnerability.

Comment: Which is why you either escape user-input, or (better yet) simply do not use any user-input.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is with a stacking or spooling pattern. It's fairly simple and can be described in 2 steps.

- Store your emails in a table with a sent flag on your current thread.
- Use cron or ajax to repeatedly call a mail processing php file that will get the top 10 or 20 unsent emails from your database, flag them as sent and actually send them via your favourite mailing method.

Comment: So now I need a database ? Urgh

Comment: for the best solution, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to async PHP
https://github.com/shuchkin/react-smtp-client

```php
$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$smtp = new \Shuchkin\ReactSMTP\Client( $loop, 'tls://smtp.google.com:465', 'username@gmail.com','password' );

$smtp->send('username@gmail.com', 'sergey.shuchkin@gmail.com', 'Test ReactPHP mailer', 'Hello, Sergey!')->then(
    function() {
        echo 'Message sent via Google SMTP'.PHP_EOL;
    },
    function ( \Exception $ex ) {
        echo 'SMTP error '.$ex->getCode().' '.$ex->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }
);

$loop->run();
```