# Is the PHP mail function synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have question about PHP mail function. Is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

synchronous, it waits for a response.

Answer (score 2):

By default it's synchronous

If you need asynchronous: [Making PHP's mail() asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540651/making-phps-mail-asynchronous)