# php sleep for only one part of the code

Tags: php, time

I need to update certain variables some time after the page has loaded.
How can I do this?

Currently I have this:

```
sleep(1);   
$introMailName1 = prepmail($sObj->username);    
$cloudnameMail = prepmail($sObj->cloud->name_en);   
$dateSubmissionMail = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sObj->upload_date);
```

I want to delay this part, where it updates the variables. But everything that comes after this also gets delayed. I need to isolate the part where the variables get updated after the page loads.

Ps. I've tried to search for this question, but couldn't find it.

Thank you!

Comment: Place `sleep()` before the part you want to delay. I don't know if that really gonna work, but you can try

Comment: I want to delay this part, where it updates the variables. But everything that comes after this also gets delayed. I need to isolate the part where the variables get updated after the page loads.

Comment: @c0dekid That's literally what he did here.

Comment: Is there some thread management in PHP? Should be interesting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273676/1870760