# my telegram bot keeps sending messages endlessly

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I Started programming a telegram bot and I've got a problem. when I send /start command it sends me a welcome message (as i programmed it) but it doesn't sends it once! it keeps sending it endlessly like loop!
this is the source:

```
<?php
    define('API_KEY','<token>');
    
    function makereq($method,$datas=[])
    {
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/".$method;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($datas));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_error($ch)){
            var_dump(curl_error($ch));
        }else{
            return json_decode($res);
        }
    }
    
    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY;
    
    $update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    
    $chat_id = $update->message->chat->id;
    $message_id = $update->message->message_id;
    $from_id = $update->message->from->id;
    $name = $update->message->from->first_name;
    $username = $update->message->from->username;
    $textmessage = isset($update->message->text)?$update->message->text:'';
    $reply = $update->message->reply_to_message->forward_from->id;
    $stickerid = $update->message->reply_to_message->sticker->file_id;
    $messageEntity = $update->messageentity->type;
    
    function SendMessage($ChatId, $TextMsg)
    {
     makereq('sendMessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$ChatId,
    'text'=>$TextMsg,
    'parse_mode'=>"MarkDown"]
     );
    }
    if($textmessage == '/start')
    {
      SendMessage($chat_id,'<welcome message>');
    }
    
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably using webhook.
If you don't respond with a http status 200 the telegram bot API thinks something is wrong with your server and requests again every few seconds as [mentioned in the API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook):

> In case of an unsuccessful request, we will give up after a reasonable
>   amount of attempts.

So just add `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` to your script and voilà!
(If your php version is greater than 5.4 you can use `http_response_code(200);` )

Answer (score 2):

If you are `polling` with `getUpdates`, you need to increment your offset.

offset = 1 + latest_update_id

IF you are using `WebHooks` ... https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update **`update_id`**

> The update‘s unique identifier. Update identifiers start from a
>   certain positive number and increase sequentially. ***This ID becomes
>   especially handy if you’re using Webhooks***, since it allows you to
>   ***ignore repeated updates*** or to restore the correct update sequence,
>   should they get out of order.

Comment: are you using webhooks or are you polling?

Comment: I'm using webhooks

Comment: ok so for webhook how should I do the increment ? just `$result ['update_id'] = ++$update;  ` ? @CharlesOkwuagwu

Comment: you can ignore repeated update ids
Telegram will simply send you latest set of updates. you don't need to do anything, if you get a repeated update_id, simply ignore

Answer (score 1):

As *Yoily L* said, you gotta return 200 before telegram thinks the request has failed.

You may use `fastcgi_finish_request()` to flush response data to the client.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

```
http_response_code(200);
fastcgi_finish_request();

// continue execution, send messages and whatever
```

Also, notice what *tuxrampage* commented in the docs:

> The script will still occupy a FPM process after
>   `fastcgi_finish_request()`. So using it excessively for long running
>   tasks may occupy all your FPM threads up to `pm.max_children`. This will
>   lead to gateway errors on the webserver.
>
> Another important thing is session handling. Sessions are locked as
>   long as they're active (see the documentation for
>   `session_write_close()`). This means subsequent requests will block
>   until the session is closed.
>
> You should therefore call `session_write_close()` as soon as possible
>   (even before `fastcgi_finish_request()`) to allow subsequent requests
>   and a good user experience.
>
> This also applies for all other locking techniques as flock or
>   database locks for example. As long as a lock is active subsequent
>   requests might bock.

You'll probably want to check

```
if (is_callable('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
    ...
}
```

More info in related question: [continue processing php after sending http response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response)

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this issue recently and stopped it by sending a blank message to the chat.  you get an error from telegram, but no more messages are sent.

Comment: This works like a charm. Also, I use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256172/1642423

Answer (score 0):

When my Telegram-bot keeped sending messages, I created a table of recording posts in the database.
When I am sending a post in my Telegram-bot, written in PHP alghorythm checks if a new post already exists in the database:
* if it does, we stop the process of sending the post;
* if it doesn't, we continue sending it in Telegram.
The described method allows to stop cycle of sending the post again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram robot due to the structure of hooks and sending and receiving messages in specified time formats
It is very sensitive to time.
I had the same problem and found that using the `date_default_timezone_set` function
This will solve the problem after deleting this function. If you have changed time templates in your code, delete them.