# How to send empty message in telegram bot?

Tags: php, keyboard, message, telegram-bot

I have this keyboard in my telegram bot:

[image]

When i click the right arrow i get this new keyboard:

[image]

the code is this:

```
    $url = $GLOBALS["website"]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=''&parse_mode=html&reply_markup=".json_encode($keyboard3);
    file_get_contents($url);
```

I know that text is required in sendmessage method, but i'm searching a way or workaround to send an empty message.

I've tried with space or similar html entity, but i did not suceed.

There is a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: It can not be done. If you want to navigate through menues without flooding your chat anytime you press a button you may want to have a look at inline_keyboards and working with callback data instead.

Comment: is there a way to put the white background for the inline_keyboards?

Comment: No, some form of text for inline_keyboards is mandatory. You can't have buttons with nothing on them.

Comment: I was referring to the background of the button, not the text.
I wanted to have the white button with black text.
I asked if it is possible to have the inline_keyboard with the white background and the black text.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Looks of buttons can not be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want.

Consider this:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botYOURTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=ID&text=
```

Since even space is not accepted, there are no other characters that can be encoded to represent "nothingness".

Answer (score 8):

You can try Alt + 0173 in the Numpad.
Press and hold the Alt key and click on 0 then 1 then 7 then 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can't send empty message now, it was a bug for zero-width space `​` and RTL (Right-to-Left) control character, but it can't send along now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the current working empty symbol for Telegram, which works as a blank bubble message with `sendMessage`.

```
ㅤ
```

Answer (score 0):

Click in the message field, hold "alt" and press 0713, this will enter a small character, release the alt key, now hold "alt" again and press 032, this will remove the small character, however telegram will still think there is a valid character there and allows you to press "send" to send a blank message