# Telegram sends multiple duplicate /start commands on Android when opened with Deep Link

Tags: android, telegram, telegram-bot, deep-linking, telegraf

We are using Referral link to open our Telegram bot. Clicking the link takes user to our Bot and hits start command with params. It works **but on Android, it sends several /start messages altogether without pressing any button.** iOS, Web and Desktop works just fine.

We are using Telegraf.js for the Bot. The issue very closely resembles this old bug, but only on Android: https://bugs.telegram.org/c/26661

On Telegraf, custom headers cannot be modified so I cannot try this solution: [my telegram bot keeps sending messages endlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593993/my-telegram-bot-keeps-sending-messages-endlessly)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.