# Return header 200 OK while using sleep in php

Tags: php, paypal, message, sleep

So I have order form and once someone filled it he transferred into paypal and make payment. Once he make the payment paypal api open my file and send me the payment data.

If paypal api doesn't get from the browser "200 OK" message it open my file again and cause me some trouble.

I use the sleep() function in php and make it wait for about 5 minutes before the file finish the load.

I want to know if it's possible to send to the browser the message "200 OK" before using the sleep() function?

I have tried to do this:

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" );
sleep(240);
```

but it doesn't seems to work. Will appreciate if someone have a way around it that might work for me. The page need to output 200 message before the sleep start.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15273676/2852578), maybe that's something you want.

Comment: virhonestum thank you so much for your help. Yes that is was i was after and it fixed me problem.