# PHP 7 continue execution after sending response

Tags: php, httpresponse, fastcgi

I am trying to send a response data to the client from a function and continue the execution. I followed the below code

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

ob_start();
// do initial processing here
echo $response; // send the response
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
// check if fastcgi_finish_request is callable
if (is_callable('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
    fastcgi_finish_request();
}
```

Got the code from the question

[continue processing php after sending http response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response)

**What I am getting is a 200 ok response only but not the data which I echoed.**

I need to get the response data too. I am using php7.1. Is there any difference of use between php5 and 7?

Please help

Comment: Use fastcgi_finish_request();

Comment: @ErnestasStankevičius You should post that as an answer and mention what it does and why it fixes the OP's problems.

Comment: @ErnestasStankevičius, I forget to mention that in my question. Updated the question. Used `fastcgi_finish_request` but it too not working.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

```
set_time_limit(0);

echo $response; // send the response

// check if fastcgi_finish_request is callable
if (is_callable('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
    fastcgi_finish_request();
}
```