# How to send a HTTP response code before proceeding?

Tags: php, http-headers, stripe-payments

Stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build#return-a-2xx-status-code-quickly) points out that:

> Because  properly  acknowledging  receipt of  the  webhook
>   notification is so important,  your endpoint should return
>   a 2xx  HTTP status code  prior to any complex  logic could
>   cause a timeout.

In the web hook I'm developing  with PHP this is exactly the
case — there is some  complex logic involved after the event
is received.

Currently I'm returning the response code with a simple call
to `http_response_code()`.  But how can I  send the response
headers (with the code) before proceeding? Would a `flush()`
call force the headers to be sent?

Comment: I would think that a flush as well as an ob_flush (after making sure there's a buffer) should do it. If a browser is involved in any way though all bets are off. It also depends on what their timeout value really is.

Comment: If you search the internet for some of those phrases from their documentation, they appear on a couple of unrelated sites so I think there's some copy-and-pasting going on. Anyway, you could use `flush` to force the headers through, but then if you had a problem later on you wouldn't be able to send an error header. My recommendation would be to ignore that recommendation (which their sample code does, too). However, if you are going to have any complex logic that might block for a couple of seconds, introduce some form of queueing on your side.

Comment: @Dave Thank you. No browser involved, this endpoint is exclusive for communication between servers.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Ah, I see. Thank you. I do perform some checks before determining the return code. So furthers erros wouldn't really be relevant to Stripe and can be handled internally. Anyway, I don't think it will block for 2 seconds. Technically it shouldn't; I'm just trying to follow their documentation. The fact that the sample code doesn't is somewhat annoying.

Comment: If any of you could post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response if you need any more info, haven't tested it