# How to force a PHP request to send the HTTP response to the client and end the request while continuing execution

Tags: java, php, android, http

I am looking for a way to send an HTTP response to a requesting android application and continue the PHP script execution after the response's termination.
The only way to achieve that that I suspect might work would be to calling fastcgi_finish_request. However I am using either mod_php or mod_fcgid but not fastcgi. Paralel is not a viable option for lack of consistent behavior between windows and linux servers as well as it preventing updates without substantial testing and reconfiguration.

Ways to achieve this are mentionned in some old [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response) but none of them seems to work in my context (php 7.4 and 8.x with apache 2.4.x) with the client being an android app (browsers do get the flushed response but the request status remains unfinished until the whole script terminates - this pending status is blocking when making the request from an android app using HttpURLConnection and I did not find a way to alter this behavior on the Android side.

For reference the current methods involve using a combination of ob and request header commands whose basis relies on:

```
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
// http request should be closed now and we should be able to do some work that does not involve sending anything back to the browser
```

or

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Variants of this method involve increasing the response body size artificially because it wouldn't flush on smaller response sizes.
I have tested all those methods to no avail. The response remains pending until the whole script terminates.
Furthermore manually setting content length might be problematic when using deflate to let apache send gzipped responses.

Someone has modified both apache and php to add a [method](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/11250)  that does that, however recompiling both is not a viable solution for production environments where those software are maintained through the distro package management framework.

My question is therefore is there any way to achieve the desired result using distro packages, either through apache configurations, from within php, or within the Android code?
Reimplementing the whole HTTP request engine on Android to gain low level control is not a realistic way to solve this issue as too many features will require too much work (such as ssl,deflate, and redirects).

I just thought of the possibility of using curl within PHP with a very low timeout to trigger a call to another script that would do the background work while not waiting for an answer to finish sending the response to the mobile app. This might work but feels like a dirty hack that's i'd prefer not to base a solution on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-threading to execute this proccess alongside HTTP request.

Example: User Sign Up with email. Response status when saved to database and another thread sending email for verification.

Comment: thanks that's a good workaround to the stated problem. I'm still hoping for an actual clean solution to it though as in my specific case the background tasks involve notifications that are time sensitive. having a cron process run every 10 seconds is not a performance catastrophe but still feels like bad design.