# How to execute php script when auction completed and browser close

Tags: php

I have problem when timer of auction process is completed then one php script is executed at server.

Because i have problem is the after start auction it is not needed browser is opened.

I have not used cron job because i need execute php script exactly when timer will be completed.

I have also AWS server so please help if you have other way to execute php process at exact time in server automatically without help of browser.

Answer (score 1):

theres 3 standard way to do this
1. cron
2. daemon
3. user driven
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759843/automatically-schedule-a-php-script-execution-at-specific-time) may help ya

Comment: okay i will check daemon and user driven because i have no idea for that.