# Asynchronously calling a PHP Script via another PHP script

Tags: php, asynchronous, shared-hosting

Let's assume I have two PHP scripts, **s1.php** and **s2.php**. Let's also assume that **s2.php** takes about 30 minutes of running.

I would like to use **s1.php** to call **s2.php** asynchronously. When **s2.php** is called, it will run on its own without returning any value to **s1.php**. **s1.php** would not wait for **s2.php** to finish; **s1.php** will continue the next command, while **s2.php** starts on its own.

So here is the pseudo code for **s1.php**

1. Do something
2. Call **s2.php**
3. Continue **s1.php**, while **s2.php** is running (this step does not need to wait for **s2.php** to return in order to continue, it immedieately startes after **s2.php** starts).

How can I do that?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I am using a shared hosting environment

Comment: Why don't you start s2 as a cli process? (Via cron, for example)

Comment: This doesn't probably qualify as full answer, but you could `curl` your `s2.php` from `s1.php` and use some of techniques described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response to quickly end response in `s2.php` and continue its execution "asynchronously".

Comment: a basic answer: `exec('php s2.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, PHP does not support async processing or threading. What you're most likely after is Queueing and/or Messaging.

This can be as simple as storing a row in a database in `s1.php` and running `s2.php` on a cron as suggested in the comments, which reads that database, pulls out new rows and executes whatever logic you need.

It would be up to you to clean up - making sure you aren't reprocessing the same rows multiple times.

Other solutions would be using something like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [IronMQ](http://iron.io).  IronMQ might be a good place to look because its a cloud based service which would work well in your shared hosting environment and they allow for a 'dev tier' account which is free and probably far more api calls then you'll ever need.

Other fun things to look at is [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/) as that does allow for non-blocking io in php.

Comment: well... PHP pthreads have come a long way! ..also, we do have pcntl_fork

Answer (score 0):

afaik, there's no good way to do this :/
you can use proc_open / exec ("nohup php5 s2.php") ~   , or $cmh=curl_multi_init(); 
$ch=curl_init("https://example.org/s2.php"); curl_multi_add_handle($chm,$ch);curl_multi_exec($chm,$foo); 
though  (or if you don't have curl, substitute with fopen...  or if allow_url_fopen is false, you can even go as far as socket_create ~~ :/ )