# Setting up queue in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5

I am trying to run code after returning a HTTP response. I know that Laravel 5 has support for [queues](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues), but I still find them confusing. I am trying to run code after the user has registered which requires the user's password and username. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469376/4938153) seems interesting, but is not directly applicable to Laravel.

- How do I create a job in a queue?
- How can I pass data to the new job?

*I know this sounds lazy and all, but I really don't understand the documentation.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting up queues requires, as the very first step, to choose what driver you'll be using. Because it's the quickest to get running, I'll explain how to begin with the `database` driver, as it doesn't require any other services to be installed on the server (as it's the case for [`beanstalkd`](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) for example). Here's how to get this set up:

**1.** Set the `QUEUE_DRIVER` in your `.env` file:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

**2.** Run this command to generate the migration file for the `jobs` table, that will be used to store job information:

```
php artisan queue:table
```

**3.** Now run the migration to create the table:

```
php artisan migrate
```

A `jobs` table was created that will store data when jobs are pushed on the queue.

---

You can push both commands and clojures onto queues. For the sake of brevity, I'll show an example of how to push a closure onto a queue:

```php
$username = Request::input('username');
$password = Request::input('password');

// Do your registration stuff

// Push a job onto the queue
\Queue::push(function($job) use ($username, $password)
{
    // Do the stuff you need here with $username and $password

    // Delete the job from the queue
    $job->delete();
});
```

---

The final step to making this work is to run the queue listener. Jobs will not be processed automatically unless the queue listener is running. So run this command:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

There are further steps you can take, such as setting up [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to monitor and restart the queue listener should it crash, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed my code, but it fails with `Class 'App\Services\Queue' not found`. I tried adding `use App\Services\Queue` to the top of the page, but that did not fix it. What am I missing?

Comment: There are two options: either use `\Queue::push()` instead of `Queue::push()`, or add `use Queue;` at the top of the file.

Comment: One more thing (tell me if this should be a new question): I am trying to run the code, but get `FatalErrorException in SerializableClosure.php(153) : eval()'d code line 86: Class 'App\Services\Auth' not found` after around 30 seconds. Does this mean the job is never really placed in the queue?

Comment: It's the same problem as with `Queue`. You're in the `App\Services` namespace. Which means that if you use `Auth`, it will automatically be assumed that the class in within that namespace and will try to load `App\Services\Auth`. That of course is not course is not correct, because all Laravel aliases are in the global namespace. So the solution is the same: you either add `use Auth;` at the top of the file or prepend a backslash like so `\Auth`. You can read more on how namespaces work in the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

Comment: @Bogdan `php artisan queue:listen` command gives `InvalidArgumentException: The "force" option doesn't exist` in Laravel 5.4

Comment: @Bogdan, could you answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331471/confused-about-laravel-5-queue-for-sending-mail-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 1):

Generally we pass data on the queue like this -

On the controller we have written -

```
$this->dispatch(new videoToAudioConvert($video_id))
```

On the job section you have to write like this -

```
protected $video_id

public function __contructor($video_id){
  $this->video_id = $video_id
}

public function handle(){
  $this->video_id
}
```

You can get more idea how to create jobs in queue and how to pass variable from [here](http://www.mashpy.me/2017/03/add-queue-in-laravel-5.1-using-beanstalkd-and-keep-it-live-with-supervisor.html).

Answer (score 0):

what is the requirement data to store in jobs table 
i use this to send email with queue and i will Schedule it 
i do the first 3 steps.
 Set the QUEUE_DRIVER in your .env file:

QUEUE_DRIVER=database
2. Run this command to generate the migration file for the jobs table, that will be used to store job information:

php artisan queue:table
3. Now run the migration to create the table:

php artisan migrate
A jobs table was created that will store data when jobs are pushed on the queue.