# Return POST Request, Then Execute CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am creating an API that receives a post request and then returns data. This data needs to be returned immediately but then I need to execute a long running curl operation after that.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $numbers = isset($_POST['numbers']) ? $_POST['numbers'] : 0;
    $numbers = $numbers*$secrethash;
    $result = array("error" => false,
        "numbers" => $numbers);
    echo json_encode($result);
    $curlfunction($numbers);
    exit;
```

Unfortunately, data is not returned until the curl function completes which causes my application to timeout. It is possible to execute the curl in the background so my data can be returned immediately?

Comment: have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continue PHP execution after sending HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response)

Comment: Adding the task to a queue and then processing via cron task was the first suggestion. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options for you.

1. You can install CRON job after outputting json content via exec() function.
2. Make AJAX request from your page after json data was returned.

Comment: AJAX is not possible because this is an API that returns data. I can create 2 APIs however and have the client call the second after receiving a response from the first! Edit: Not very good API design though :P

Comment: Ended up creating a second API containing the CURL and calling that after receiving a response from the first. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the function in a separate file and execute it similar to this. This would cause a separate process to be created. Maybe write the result to a file and read it. Set up your php to take your variable as a parameter.

exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php > /dev/null &");

It might be worth a shot. :-)