# Running script in background using php curl

Tags: php, curl, background-process

I want to run a function as background process using curl. Below is my code.

```
  foreach ($iles $file=> $size) {

                $params ="file=$file&fullpath=$fullpath&minWidth=$minWidth";
                $url = 'http://test.rul.com/file/listFiles?'.$params;
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                $curled=curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
            }
        }


     public function getlistFiles() {
 $fullpath = $_REQUEST['fullpath'];
 }
```

but this curl is not running on background. how can I execute this as background ?

Comment: this works. but you need to force a curl timeout. and make sure the called script continues running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continue PHP execution after sending HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response)

Comment: check out this answer. that works great: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41263257/4379151

Comment: 2nd script must use `ignore_user_abort(true);`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken curl didnt work after adding timeout , any reasons ?

Comment: I posted a full example as answer. Its what I am using in my class to call scripts asynchronously. Proven to work.

Comment: Of course you will get a curl error CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT every time. you can just ignore it

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for the calling script with curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 400); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

2nd script

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
usleep(500000);    // wait 500ms
// do stuff
```

Note that you will always get a curl error `CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT`, which can be ignored.