# PHP drop HTTP connection

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [close a connection early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early)
>   [How to continue process after responding to ajax request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481247/how-to-continue-process-after-responding-to-ajax-request-in-php)

I need to drop connection in ajax actions:

```
$response = getResponse($params);
echo $response; // don't make user to wait
flushAndDropConnection();
someLongActionsFor5Seconds();
```

How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to continue process after responding to ajax request in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481247/how-to-continue-process-after-responding-to-ajax-request-in-php) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806637/continue-processing-after-closing-connection or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early or

Comment: You should read discussions in the PHP documentation for `flush()`. This post specifically: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#91556

Comment: The solution in duplicate doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the user disconnect, but leave the script running.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo "response";
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
header('Connection: close');
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
if (session_id()) session_write_close();
//your long running action here
```

Comment: I think I should calc content-length before connection:close?

Comment: PHP should do that automatically.

Comment: BTW haders should be before any output.

Comment: I tested the code: it doesn't work on my linux server without content-length header.